# Color a choropleth map in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, maps

I am new to d3.js and javascript and I have to create a bivariate choropleth map. I have managed to successfully create the map, however, I am having some trouble trying to color it.

I want to achieve sth like this: https://observablehq.com/@awsherman/bivariate-choropleth-mapping

So far this is what I have managed to do:

```
maparea.selectAll('path')
      .data(mapStatesUSA.features)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', path)
      .attr('transform', 'scale(0.9) translate(60,0)')
      .attr('class', 'country');

      maparea.selectAll('path')
      .data(this.fulldata)
      .attr('fill', (d) => this.mapColor(this.fulldata.get(d.state)));
 
let color = {
      return [
      '#73ae80', '#5a9178', '#2a5a5b',
      '#b8d6be', '#90b2b3', '#567994',
      '#e8e8e8', '#b5c0da', '#6c83b5']
    },

let xColor = d3.scaleQuantile(Array.from(this.fulldata.valueBurglary, d => d[0], 3));
 
let yColor = d3.scaleQuantile(Array.from(this.fulldata.value, (d) => d[1], 3));

const mapColor = {
      return d => {
        if (!d) return 'N/A';
        let[a, b] = d;
        return this.color[this.yColor(b) * this.xColor(a) * 3];
      };
```

I have tried to replicate the code from the link above. However, I have to admit I don't understand very well what is going on. I would really appreciate it if someone could give a hand on how to do this. Thank you!